gio mount fails with volume doesn't implement mount
gio mount can fail with volume doesn't implement mount if you pass gio a second argument for the mountpoint like you would with the traditional mount command.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

gio automatically creates a suitable mount point, which does not need to be specified in the gio mount command, and which is also automatically deleted when the file system is unmounted. The location of this mount point depends on the type of mounted location.
